# Rails 5: users(devise) and managing multiple tables on a single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller

I have had this working using Laravel but am attempting to get this together in a Rails app now.

Basically I currently have setup a new Rails app with the following steps:

1. `rails new MyApp`
2. Installed devise

   - Add devise to Gemfile
   - `bundle`
   - `rails g devise:install`
3. Setup custom devise controllers and views

   - `rails g devise:controllers users`
   - `rails g devise:views users`
4. Added custom fields for devise user & updated new/edit views

Uptill this point, everything works fine. I am able to login/logout and communicate with database properly.

**UPDATE**

*First part of my question*

How to bring in a row relating to the user onto a specific page has been answered by Saqib Shahzad's answer.

For all intensive purposes, I have setup a Home controller and related view that allows me to bring in all the related information.

*This is the second part*

Now what I want to do is create a row for the user on a separate table at the same time that the user is created.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one :order
end
```

order.rb:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

order migration:

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      ...
end
```

So, assuming that I am using devise... How, when the user is created, can the necessary row be created in the Orders table so that after registration, they can immediately see their order information. (It would obviously just show the default values of the fields as they did not edit anything yet)

So...

1. Person fills in registration information on registration page.
2. Person clicks submit
3. Both users and orders tables are given a new row for the new user (User and the user's Order is created)
4. Person is immediately redirected to their homepage that shows them their order values

Comment: I am assuming everything is linked with user_id, So you can get everything in a single page in RoR.

Comment: So, I should make a seperate "Home" Controller, that brings in all the information I need on that one page. So I would not setup any index/new/destroy methods in the "Orders" Controller, I would instead just call the show and update methods of "Orders" in the RESTful methods on the "Home" Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I have understood from your question is, you want to display each user only his orders on a page, preferably `homepage`. It's very simple.

Create a `Home Controller` and an action, you can name it whatever you want `dashboard`/`homepage`/`my_orders`.

```
def homepage
  @order = current_user.order
end
```

And in your views, `home/homepage`:

display whatever information you want to display: For example:

```
if @order.present?
    @order.name
    link_to "Edit", edit_order_path
    link_to "Destroy",@order,method: :delete
else
    link_to "create order", new_order_path
end
```

`new_order_path` will take the user to the form of creating new order (orders controller)

In your `orders_controller` new action, instead of initializing,

```
@order = Order.new
```

initialize as:

```
@order = current_user.order.new
```

I hope this clears any confusions.

**UPDATE:**

If you want the order to be created automatically right when the user is created, then you can do this with `after_commit` methods.

In you `user.rb` model, create the order after a user is created by:

```
after_create_commit {self.order.create(name: "somename",other_attribute: "value")}
```

Comment: Reading your example has clarified a lot confusion I was having. So then for the second part of my question; if I were to want to add a new row to another table on the user creation so that the user has an 'order', I would just use this same process and add a 'create' method for the new order in the same action that creates the user?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question, you said User will have one Order, then why will be he needing to create another order if he already has one order?

Comment: This is in reference to the second part of my question. The user would have no related row in the orders table until the user is created. So i could just create that upon creation of the user in the same way you described

Comment: I have updated my answer, and as you said, user will not have any order, when no user is created and as the user is not created, how will he able to log in and visit this page.

Comment: Yes user can create the order by visiting that page, if he has any order, it will be displayed on that page, otherwise he can create a new order.And If  my answer probably answers your questions, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. I do not want the user to be able to create an order. Each user only has one order and can only update the qtys of the order, each field is a qty of a specific item. I am trying to get their related row on the orders table to be created at the same time that the user is created. I have edited my original question to help clarify.

Comment: That is it! Thank you very much